# No Module found error while deploying django on apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I have been trying to deploy django on apache, this is my httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/home/naveen/cloudserver:/home/naveen/cloudserver
        WSGIScriptAlias /radi /home/naveen/cloudserver/cloudserver/wsgi.py application-group=%{GLOBAL} process-group=app1

        <Directory /home/naveen/cloudserver/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /home/naveen/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and this is my wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cloudserver.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

when i try to open this application i get internal server error, this is my log file which shows the following errors

```
[Wed Dec 26 08:42:42.730573 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1846]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Wed Dec 26 08:42:42.730578 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1846]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Dec 26 08:42:42.730595 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1846] ImportError: No module named 'cloudserver'
```

it says module not found cloudserver, how to resolve this error? cloudserver module is present in that folder?I have been stuck in this stage for almost 2 days, every tutorial i try to use endup in this error.How to properly configure my django project to run on apache?

**Update**
This is my directory structure, it is located in /home/naveen/

[image: my directory structure]

Comment: clouderver is a folder *within* /home/naveen/cloudserver? Show your directory structure. And why have you listed it twice in the pythonpath?

Comment: updated the question, thanks.